# Как проверить множество элементов в списке?

Tags: python

Как проверить множество элементов в списке?
Или же как упростить это:

```
x = '01234'

if ('0' in x) and ('1'in x) and ('2' in x) and ('3' in x) and ('4' in x):....
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

например так:

```
lst = ['0', '1', '2', '3', ...]
x = '01234'

if all(l in x for l in lst):
```

или так:

```
if set(lst).difference(x) == set():
```